# Why apache 2.4.9 does not allow remote connections if I have enabled "Require all granted" on httpd.conf

Tags: apache, wamp

I have installed WAMPSERVER 2.5 on Windows server 2008 R2 and it works ok, but I want to have public access to the server from outside the local network. I have read that I should write "Require all granted" inside the tag "Directory", but I still have no public access, so what else could I do?

Comment: I have checked the firewall also, but still cannot get public access

Comment: Does your server have a public IP address?

Comment: Have you Port Forwarded port 80 on your router.

Answer (score 0):

As I have IIS and apache on the same machine, I had to change the port of apache to Listen to 82 and the problem was that the port was not allowing incoming connections due to the firewall.